# I can get the permalink or the excerpt to work correctly, but not both

Tags: permalinks, filters, excerpt

I'm calling the following code from within a filter hook. (I'm using the_ rather than get_the for bugsquashing clarity.)

```
function test_function($output, $format, $link, $post, $adjacent) {

    //throwing away arguments for bugsquashing clarity

    $post_id='6';

    //global $post;
    $post = get_post ($post_id);
    setup_postdata ($post);       

    the_permalink();
    the_excerpt();

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'test_function', 10, 5);
```

If I use the above code, then I receive the following output:

- The link to the page I'm on
- The excerpt from the page with ID=6

If I uncomment the global $post line for the following code, I receive this

- The link to the page with ID=6
- No excerpt from anywhere

What I'd like is to receive the link and excerpt from the page with ID=6.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: On a fresh install it works correctly in situation 2 (ie provides link and excerpt), and has the same results in situation 1.

So I'm guessing global needs to be set, and the problem is something to do with my hooks.

Comment: I can't duplicate this. I get the permalink and the excerpt that I expect with or without the `global` line.

Comment: Just tried on a fresh install. Global line commented out still gives me the situation as above.

If the global line is uncommented, then it works as I would expect.

Comment: Filter line added for clarity.

Comment: Your use of the filter function is completely wrong. Please see the [`{$adjacent}_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/adjacent_post_link/) filter and all of its parameters

Comment: I discarded all of the parameters in order to show the problem, which is that the_excerpt is not showing. Code amended to make this clear.

In the live site (rather than the test install) the code is running through a different set of hooks. I'll attempt to duplicate the bug on a test install, and post an update at that point.